# how to get the partitions info of hive table in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive-metastore

I want to execute the SQL by Spark like this.

```
sparkSession.sql("select * from table")
```

But I want to have a partition check on the table before execution avoiding fullscan.

If the table is a partitioned table, my program will force users to add a partition filter. If not it's ok to run.

So my question is how to know whether a table is a partitioned table?
My thought is that reading info from metastore. but how to get metastore is another problem I encounter. Could someone help?

Comment: `show partitions table`?

Comment: Are you using PySpark or Scala API ?

Comment: It's ok to do this in this way. But Is there a graceful way? like some api

Comment: @philantrovert scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your real goal is to restrict execution of unbounded queries, I think it would be easier to get query's execution plan and look under its `FileScan` / `HiveTableScan` leaf nodes to see if any partition filters are being applied. For partitioned tables, number of partitions that query is actually going to scan will also be presented, by the way. So, something like this should do:

```
scala> val df_unbound = spark.sql("select * from hottab")
df_unbound: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, descr: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val plan1 = df_unbound.queryExecution.executedPlan.toString
plan1: String =
"*(1) FileScan parquet default.hottab[id#0,descr#1,loaddate#2] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, 
Location: CatalogFileIndex[hdfs://ns1/user/hive/warehouse/hottab], 
PartitionCount: 365, PartitionFilters: [],
PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,descr:string>
"

scala> val df_filtered = spark.sql("select * from hottab where loaddate='2019-07-31'")
df_filtered: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, descr: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val plan2 = df_filtered.queryExecution.executedPlan.toString
plan2: String =
"*(1) FileScan parquet default.hottab[id#17,descr#18,loaddate#19] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, 
Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://ns1/user/hive/warehouse/hottab/loaddate=2019-07-31], 
PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(loaddate#19), (loaddate#19 = 2019-07-31)], 
PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,descr:string>
"
```

This way, you also don't have to deal with SQL parsing to find table name(s) from queries, and to interrogate metastore yourself.

As a bonus, you'll be also able to see if "regular" filter pushdown occurs (for storage formats that support it) in addition to partition pruning.

Comment: it helps a lot, what i'm trying to do is excatly what you said. but in your case, do I have to run the sql before get the execution plan?

Comment: No, `queryExecution` builds execution plan without actually running it.

Comment: I found that sparksql.table().explain can do the same thing too. Do I have to parse the execution plan if I want to get the partition cols names?

Comment: I got it! 
 sparkSession.catalog.listColumns(s"$hiveDbName.$hiveTbName").collect().mkString  where the output contains what I want part of Output: Column[name='day', dataType='string', nullable='true', isPartition='true', isBucket='false']Column[name='hour', dataType='string', nullable='true', isPartition='true', isBucket='false']

Comment: I think it does, output format is slightly different thats all (partition columns are printed as separate array following "regular" ones).

Comment: Besides, running queries against tables stored as textfiles is a bad idea to begin with. This format is often used in transient/staging phase of ETL, before data is loaded into DW in queryable formats. So since you're playing a "query police" :)) you can disallow these queries altogether!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scala's `Try` class and execute `show partitions` on the required table.

```scala
val numPartitions = Try(spark.sql("show partitions database.table").count) match {
    case Success(v) => v
    case Failure(e) => -1
}
```

Later you can check `numPartitions`. If the value is `-1` then the table is not partitioned.

Comment: Yes. I think it's a tricky way to implement like what @Lamanus and you say. I wanna know is there a better way? something Like val table = metastore.getTable("table") & val partitions = table.getpartitions

Comment: Hive's metastore is usually on a RDBMS. You'll need to connect to the metastore via JDBC and then fire a query to know if the table is partitioned or not. This, imo, is an easier solution.

Comment: yes thank you sir! It's also a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  val listPartitions = spark.sessionState.catalog.listPartitionNames(TableIdentifier("table_name", Some("db name")))
  listPartitions: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(partition1=value1, ... )  // partition table
  listPartitions: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer() // not partition table
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but this might help someone

```
spark.sql("describe detail database.table").select("partitionColumns").show(false)
```

this is give the row with the partitioned columns in a array

[image]